# .agg on a group inside a groupby object?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Sorry if this has been asked before, I couldn't find it.

I have census population dataframe that contains the population of each county in the US.

The relevant part of `df` looks like:

```
+----+--------+---------+----------------------------+---------------+
|    | REGION | STNAME  | CTYNAME                    | CENSUS2010POP |
+----+--------+---------+----------------------------+---------------+
| 1  | 3      | Alabama | Autauga County             | 54571         |
+----+--------+---------+----------------------------+---------------+
| 2  | 3      | Alabama | Baldwin County             | 182265        |
+----+--------+---------+----------------------------+---------------+
| 69 | 4      | Alaska  | Aleutians East Borough     | 3141          |
+----+--------+---------+----------------------------+---------------+
| 70 | 4      | Alaska  | Aleutians West Census Area | 5561          |
+----+--------+---------+----------------------------+---------------+
```

How I can get the np.std of the states population (sum of counties' population) for each of the four regions in the US without modifying the `df`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation):

```
df['std_col'] = df.groupby('STNAME')['CENSUS2010POP'].transform("std")
```

IIUC, if you want sum of counties, you do:

```
state_pop = df.groupby('STNAME')['CTYNAME'].nunique().apply(np.std)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly use the standard deviation method `std()`

```
 new_df=df.groupby(['REGION'])[['CENSUS2010POP']].std()
```